# Spring Boot Kafka: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Today, in my Spring Boot and single instance Kafka application I faced the following issue:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot
>   be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the
>   partitions to another member. This means that the time between
>   subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured
>   max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is
>   spending too much time message processing. You can address this either
>   by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of
>   batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

What may be the reason for this and how to fix it? As far as I understand - my consumer was blocked for a long time and didn't respond for the heartbeat. And I should adjust Kafka properties in order to address it. Could you please tell me what exact properties should I adjust and where, for example on the Kafka side or on my application Spring Kafka side?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default Kafka will return a batch of records of `fetch.min.bytes` (default 1) up to either `max.poll.records` (default 500), or `fetch.max.bytes` (default 52428800), otherwise it will wait `fetch.wait.max.ms` (default 100) before returning a batch of data. Your consumer is expected to do some work on that data and then call `poll()` again. Your consumer's work is expected to be completed within `max.poll.interval.ms` (default 300000 — 5 mins in pre v2.0 and 30000 - 30 seconds post v2.0). If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

So to fix your issue, reduce the number of messages returned, or increase `max.poll.interval.ms` property to avoid timing out and rebalancing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please tell me where exactly I have to set `max.poll.interval.ms` property?

Comment: Sure, set it in the properties you pass to the consumer when you create it, in the plain java client you'd set it in the `Properties` object passed to `new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);` call.

Comment: Note that `max.poll.interval.ms` was changed to 30 sec starting from v2.0.0

Comment: queit logical...i guess its takes some planning before deploying an ideal consumer!