# Springboot Kafka - Consumer idempotence

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Spring-boot application which listens to kafka. To avoid duplicate processing, I am trying to do manual commit. For this I referred [Commit Asynchronously a message just after reading from topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354721/commit-asynchronously-a-message-just-after-reading-from-topic). But I am stuck at how can I achieve ***consumer idempotence*** so that records will not get processed twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as an idempotent (exactly once) consumer with Kafka.

Kafka **does** provide exactly once semantics for

```
kafkaRead -> process -> kafkaWrite
```

But the "exactly once" applies to the whole flow only. The `process` step is `at least once`.

In other words, the offset for the read is only committed if the write is successful. If the write fails, the read/process/write will be performed again.

This is implemented using [Kafka transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions).

If you are interacting with some other store in the `process` step (or are not doing kafka writes at all - `kafkaRead -> process`) you have to write your own idempotent (de-duplication) code.

But this is relatively easy because the consumer record has a unique key via `topic/partition/offset` - just store those with the data and check that you have not already processed that record.

Kafka **does** support idempotent producers.

Comment: That seems to be perfect. Is there any optimized way to store the record from Kafka, compare every time newly fetched record to check whether it is already processed or not? I can think of traditional approaches like storing in database or cache.